# opencv pkg-config: cannot find -lopencv_ts when compiling using g++

Tags: linux, opencv, g++, pkg-config, yocto

I added opencv and g++, gcc to my yocto distro (linux based) on wandboard-quad (iMX6). When I try to compile a test opencv program using:

```
g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename test.cpp .cpp` test.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

It show error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.9.1/../../../../arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_ts
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

things I checked:

```
pkg-config --cflags opencv
-I/usr/include/opencv

pkg-config --libs opencv 
-lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab -lm -ldl
```

So I found a similar question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/39014/opencv-pkg-config-configuration-problem-in-ubuntu-with-fuerte/)  and try to set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`:(in /usr/lib/pkgconfig there is opencv.pc)

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/lib/pkgconfig
echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
:/usr/lib/pkgconfig
```

compile it again, still reports the same error.

Don't know what to do now. So any thoughts or suggestions are extremely welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this error once, simply add `IMAGE_INSTALL += "opencv-staticdev"` to your recipe.